# Number of k-vectors which sum of components is equal to n.

Tags: combinatorics

Given two integers $k>0$ and $n>0$, what is the number of vectors of size $k$ (which components are non-negative integers) such that the sum of their components is equal to $n$?

Example: For $k=2$, $n=3$, the answer is $4$, since the corresponding vectors are: $\{(0,3), (1,2), (2,1), (3,0)\}$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Imagine writing the components in unary notation: i, ii, iii, iiii and so forth. Then each of the vectors you're looking for is written with $n$ 'i's and $k-1$ commas, in some order. Does every such order correspond to a solution?

Comment: Ha yes that's true, thank you. Then, maybe it comes down to counting the number of partitions of a given set of size n into k subsets? That would be a kind of variant of the Bell number, which corresponds to the number of partitions (of any size) of a given set of size n..

Comment: Review the [technique of stars and bars](https://brilliant.org/assessment/techniques-trainer/stars-and-bars/).

Comment: $n+k-1 \choose k-1$. Thank you very much for your quick replies!